# What can trigger login session expiration in Firebase Auth system

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am observing login session expiration in my iOS app, like this:

```
 private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

 handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
     //do some stuff      
 }

 if let `handle` = handle {
    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
 }
```

I wonder what can trigger session to be closed except `Auth.auth().signOut()` ?
I guess user deletion in firebase or something like that. What cases I should cover in `stateDidChange` listener block?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-addauthstatedidchangelistener:

Comment: Looks like signing in, signing out (for multiple users), registration as a listener, and admin revoke of access

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Firebase is limited to Javascript for web apps and the Admin SDK. That said, since Firebase sessions are managed via JWT ID tokens that have a relatively short life and rely on refresh tokens to renew them, a user's auth state could change if the token refresh fails. A refresh could fail if the user's refresh token was revoked (possibly by an administrator using the capabilities of the Admin SDK), or if the user's account was disabled, or possibly if there's a major change to the user's account like a password or email change.